# HJM model, existence of arbitrage:

Tags: bond, arbitrage, yield-curve, no-arbitrage-theory, heath-jarrow-morton

**The Setup:**

---

Suppose I know the yield curve of a Bond satisfies:
f (0, t) = 0.04 for t ≥ 0 and
f (ω, 1, t) = 0.06, t ≥ 1, ω = ω 1 ,
0.02, t ≥ 1, ω = ω 2 ,
where Ω = {ω 1 , ω 2 } with P[ω i ] > 0, i = 1, 2.

And suppose that I know the matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix}
P (0, 1) & P (0, 2) & P (0, 3)\\
P (ω_1 , 1, 1) & P (ω_1 , 1, 2)&  P (ω_1 , 1, 3) \\
P (ω_2 , 1, 1) & P (ω_2 , 1, 2) & P (ω_2 , 1, 3)
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^{-0.04}&e^{-0.04}&e^{-0.04}\\
1&e^{-0.06}&e^{-0.12} \\
1&e^{-0.02}&e^{-0.04}
\end{pmatrix}
$ is invertible (for example, I have shown that it's determinant is roughly equal t$0.0004258212$).

---

**The Question:**

How can I show that there exists an arbitrage opportunity using the above matrix and the following value process:\
\begin{align}
V (ω_1 , 1) = & 1 = V (ω_2 , 1)\\
V(ω_1 ,0) = & 0 = V(ω_2 ,0).  
\end{align}

---

**Context:**
This example is supposed to help motivate why parallel shifts along yield curves yields arbitrage opportunities.

Comment: The notation is not clear. For example, what does $V (ω_1 , 1)$ mean. It is better to define the notations before you use them.

Comment: $V:\Omega\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a stochastic process, so the first component is the outcome in the probability space $\Omega$ and the second is the time variable, the rest is the usual stuff.

Comment: What is $P (ω 1 , 1, 1)$?

Comment: P is the price of the bond: ie: $P(\omega,t,T)=e^{-\int_t^T f(\omega,u,T)du}$, where $T$ is the time of maturity of the Bond and $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the 2nd matrix is incorrect; P(t,T)=-f(t,T) * (T-t)